# C string type definition

Tags: c

I was just trying to make a string like type when you could just write:

```
string s;
```

And I thought to do it like:

```
#define string char *
```

Then for example in main function I have to write only `string s;` and if I type different variable name then it doesn't work.

How can I improve the definition or maybe how can I use "typedef" for this job if it's not a bad practice to do it so. Or is there any better approach to make variables type of string?
I was searching but I think I couldn't find the answer.

Comment: Read the advice given by [Keith Thompson](http://stackoverflow.com/users/827263/keith-thompson) in my answer comments, if you are learning you should also learn good practices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You *can't* make variables of type string in C, because "string" is not a type.

A "string" is, by definition, "a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character". It's not a data type, it's a data format.

An array of `char` may *contain* a string. A `char*` may *point to* a string. Neither of them *is* a string.

If you like, you can define

```
typedef char *string; /* not recommended */
```

but that's misleading, since a variable of type `char*`, as I mentioned, isn't a string.

The best practice is simply to use `char*` directly. This makes it clear that your variable is a pointer. It's also consistent with the way the standard library is defined; for example, the `strlen` function is declared as:

```
size_t strlen(const char *s);
```

It's also consistent with the way most experienced C programmers write code that deals with strings.

Because of the way C treats arrays (more or less as second-class citizens), arrays, including arrays that contain strings, are usually manipulated via pointers to their elements. We can use pointer arithmetic to traverse an array. Pretending that the pointer *is* the array, or that it *is* a string, is tempting, and might seem to make the code more understandable, but in the long run it just causes confusion.

A macro approach like

```
#define string char*
```

is even worse than a `typedef`. Macros are expanded as sequences of tokens; the processor doesn't know about the syntax of C declarations. So given the above definition, this:

```
string x, y;
```

expands to

```
char* x, y;
```

which defines `x` as a `char*` and `y` as a `char`. If you need a name for a type, `typedef` is almost always better than `#define`.

Comment: Great thanks for the explanation! I saw the string type in one source file I was interested how could one make it work that way.I think I'll go for classic approach with char*.

Comment: *It is not a type it's a data format*, then what is `typedef` useful for?

Comment: @iharob: `typedef` creates an alias for an existing type. It's useful when you already have an existing type, but having a different name for it will make the code clearer. For example, `size_t` is defined in `<stddef.h>` as a typedef for some implementation-defined unsigned integer type. The name `size_t` is more informative than the name of the underlying type; it tells you that it's the type of the result of the `sizeof` operator, for example.

Comment: @KeithThompson so `typedef struct { /* definition */ } SomeStruct;` is bad practice?

Comment: @iharob: Opinions vary. Plenty people use typedefs for structs so that the type can be referred to by a one-word name `Foo` rather than `struct Foo`. My personal preference is *not* to use the typedef, but refer to the type by its name `struct Foo`. A typedef certainly makes sense if you want to hide the fact that it's a struct, i.e., if client code never refers to any of its members but only uses functions provided by the interface. But there's nothing *wrong* with providing a typedef just for the sake of a shorter name, and plenty of very smart people do it.

Comment: @iharob: Note that in C++, unlike in C, `struct Foo { /* ... */ };` makes the name `Foo` directly visible, so in C++ such a typedef would be redundant. But C is C, and C++ is C++, and IMHO it rarely makes sense to cater to one language's rules when writing in the other.

Answer (score 3):

You have to learn what the [Preprocessor](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/) is. As for your problem, the right solution is

```
typedef char *string;
```

and if you want to use the preprocessor remove the semi colon and the `s` like this

```
#define string char *
```

In the second case the preprocessor will replace each occurence of `string` with `char *`, and hence if you declare

```
string x, y;
```

it will expand to

```
char *x, y;
```

where `x` if a pointer to `char` and `y` is simply a `char`, this is misleading and should be avoided.

One more thing, when working in C it is never a good Idea to hide the fact that some variable is a pointer, so things like

```
typedef SomeType *SomeTypeName;
```

where `SomeType` could be any type, are generally a bad idea, you can do something I've seen that clarifies this a little, you can append a `P` to `SomeType`, like this

```
typedef SomeType *SomeTypeP;
```

but I personally prefer the `*` to any of these `typedef`s

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm beginner. yeah I just accidentally typed semicolon.

Comment: The `#define` is a really bad idea; `string x, y;` would make `x` a `char*` and `y` a `char`. The `typedef` avoids that problem, but it isn't much better. A `char*` isn't a string; it *points to* a string. Don't hide that fact behind a `typedef`. Just use `char*` directly.

Comment: I've expanded the preceding comment to [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27551702/827263).

Comment: There is no good reason to downvote my answer without commenting, I my self suggested to read Keith Thompson's comment.

Answer (score -1):

Don't. `string` is a C++ keyword. Not only it will cause problems if C++ becomes involved, but more importantly, it causes confusion and hides the fact that you are dealing with a pointer.

UPDATE: Right guys, it's not a keyword. But if like many people you put `using namespace std;` in your code, then `string` is a C++ class from the standard library.

What I wanted to say is that it is not a common practice to make an alias for `char *` and it might confuse other people looking at your code.

Comment: `string` isn't a keyword in C++. Might cause issues in combination with `using namespace std;` or the like indeed, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: no `string` is a C++ class from the [STL](https://www.google.co.ve/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CD0QFjAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sgi.com%2Ftech%2Fstl%2F&ei=rgOTVKK2LvOBsQTBiIHoBQ&usg=AFQjCNH-qpY6JwRTDNCor-h5IQp4IRNNjg&bvm=bv.82001339,d.cWc).

Comment: I will go for String then I'm just using pure C here. Thanks

Comment: Suggestion: fix your answer with the details above.

Comment: @iharob No, it's from the standard library, not STL.